# How to avoid Blockhound catching blocking call when setting up data?

Tags: spring-webflux

In my integration test I'm using BlockHound to capture any blocking call.
For setting up the data I am doing a blocking call because I want the data to be persisted in the DB when running each test.
When running the integration test Blockhound is throwing an error at the set up method: **reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes**

How to avoid this?

```
      @BeforeAll
      public static void blockHoundSetup() {
        BlockHound.install();
      }
    
      @BeforeEach
      public void setUp() {
        stagingAreaAdapter.deleteAll()
            .thenMany(Flux.fromIterable(data))
            .flatMap(stagingAreaAdapter::save)
            .blockLast();
      }
```

Comment: did you set `BlockHound.install()` inside your main method?

Comment: This worked:
  @BeforeAll
  public static void blockHoundSetup() {
    BlockHound.builder()
        .allowBlockingCallsInside(TestClass.class.getName(), "setUp")
        .install();
  }
Basically configure Blockhound on build to ignore this blocking call.

Comment: By the way, you can avoid the `static` keyword at `static void blockHoundSetupt()` method by using `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` annotation in your class.

Answer (score 3):

Check BlockHound customizations for allowing and disallowing blocking calls inside methods:
https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound/blob/master/docs/customization.md#dis-allowing-blocking-calls-inside-methods

**1.** using builder in a @BeforeAll method (as per [@KrisKris1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66674587/896981)):

```java
@BeforeAll 
public static void blockHoundSetup() { 
    BlockHound.builder().allowBlockingCallsInside(
        TestClass.class.getName(), "setUp").install(); 
}
```

or

**2.** via implementing the `BlockHoundIntegration` interface (still applies globally):

```java
public class BlockHoundCustomConfiguration implements BlockHoundIntegration {

    @Override
    public void applyTo(BlockHound.Builder builder) {
        builder.allowBlockingCallsInside("java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile", "readBytes");
    }
}
```

and create the following file:
`<project dir>/src/test/resources/META-INF/services/reactor.blockhound.integration.BlockHoundIntegration`
with your custom class:

```
com.example.config.BlockHoundCustomConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow blocking method calls inside `java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream#read` down the callstack.

Add in your BlockHound customization config.

```
public class ReactorBlockHoundIntegration implements BlockHoundIntegration {

    @Override
    public void applyTo(BlockHound.Builder builder) {
      builder.allowBlockingCallsInside(InflaterInputStream.class.getName(), "read");
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/package-summary.html